# duplicate entry for username

Tags: users

I am creating a user account programmatically with the following code.

```
$fields = array(
  'name' => $first_name,
  'mail' => $mail,
  'pass' => $password,
  'status' => 1,
  'init' => $mail,
);

$account = user_save('', $fields);
```

When I am trying with same name again, it throws an error, but by default it updates the name.

How do I update the name if already exist?

Comment: according to the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) and function's source code, first argument should be an object representing user, or `NULL`. Empty string may mess a bit. And what was that error? It's hard to fix something we can't see, right?

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Pkfd' for key 'name': INSERT INTO {users} (uid, name, mail, created, status, init, data, uuid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 364 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => Pkfd [

Comment: it is showing duplicate entry for name. i.e username ..

Comment: @Rashmi The `name` column on the `users` table has a unique index set on it, so you can't insert two records with the same value for that column. One solution would be to check the output from [`user_load_by_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7) first, then alter the name based on whatever criteria you feel is appropriate for your user-naming conventions

Comment: @Rashmi please edit your question instead of adding data in comments. And Clive is kinda right, you cannot have duplicated names so you should check before save. Unless you want to update the very user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something very simple like this, using [`user_load_by_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7), would be an option:

```
$original_username = $username = 'something';
$count = 1;
while (user_load_by_name($username)) {
  $username = $original_username . $count++;
}

$fields = array(
  'name' => $username,
  ...
```

That will keep on trying 'something', 'something1', 'something2', 'something3', etc. until it finds a unique name.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution can be:

- Add this function to return unique user name

  ```
  function _mymodule_unique_username($name, $uid = 0) {
    // Strip illegal characters.
    $name = preg_replace('/[^\x{80}-\x{F7} a-zA-Z0-9@_.\'-]/', '', $name);

    // Strip leading and trailing spaces.
    $name = trim($name);

    // Convert any other series of spaces to a single underscore.
    $name = preg_replace('/ +/', '_', $name);

    // If there's nothing left use a default.
    $name = ('' === $name) ? t('user') : $name;

    // Truncate to reasonable size.
    $name = (drupal_strlen($name) > (USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH - 10)) ? drupal_substr($name, 0, USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH - 11) : $name;

    // Iterate until we find a unique name.
    $i = 0;

    do {
     $new_name = empty($i) ? $name : $name . '_' . $i;
     $found = db_query_range("SELECT uid from {users} WHERE uid <> :uid AND name = :name", 0, 1, array(':uid' => $uid, ':name' => $new_name))->fetchAssoc();
     $i++;
    } while (!empty($found));

    return $new_name;
  }
  ```
- Call it

  ```
  // Get the updated name.
  $name = _mymodule_unique_username($first_name);
  $language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  // Set up the user fields.    
  $fields = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'mail' => $mail,
    'pass' => $password,
    'status' => 1,
    'init' => $mail,
  );

  $account = user_save('', $fields);
  ```

Comment: it returns same username

Comment: just change
function _mymodule_unique_username($name) 
to
function _mymodule_unique_username($name, $uid=0) 
you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You may try Real name module for your users. 
or this snippet of code may help you

```
if ((bool) db_query("SELECT 1 FROM {users} WHERE uid <> :uid AND LOWER(name) = LOWER(:new_name)", array(
      ':uid' => $account->uid,
      ':new_name' => $new_name
    ))->fetchField()
    ) {
      $name_idx = db_query_range("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'_',-1) FROM {users} WHERE name REGEXP :search ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'_',-1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC", 0, 1, array(':search' => '^' . $new_name . '_[0-9]+$'))->fetchField();
      $new_name .= '_' . ($name_idx + 1);
    }
```